# Кодировка в оконных программах

Tags: кодировка, ассемблер, кириллица, masm32, masm

Вот я не давно пробовал делать консольные программы, но там к сожалению какие-то не стыковки с кириллицей, на XP всё работает хорошо, а в win 10, абракадабра. Попробовал сделать оконную программу, ну вообщем сделал, но вот когда я захотел поставить русский текст на одну из кнопок, то правильно как вы и догадались, на кнопке опять же не текст а какая-то ерунда :(((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
      .486                      ; create 32 bit code
      .model flat, stdcall      ; 32 bit memory model
      option casemap :none      ; case sensitive

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
      include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\Comctl32.inc
      include \masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
      include \masm32\include\shell32.inc
      include \masm32\include\oleaut32.inc
      include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
      include \masm32\include\dialogs.inc
      include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

      includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\oleaut32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
     Main   PROTO  

.data?
hIcon           Dd ?
hBrush         Dd ?
hCursor       Dd ?
hImage        Dd ?
hInstance    Dd ?

.data
wc      WNDCLASS <?>
newhwnd dd 0
hDC dd 0
szTitleName     db 'Window Application',0
msg     MONMSGSTRUCT <?> ; 
szClassName     db 'ASMCLASS32',0
ps    PAINTSTRUCT <?>
rct   RECT <?>


.code

start:
  mov hInstance, FUNC(GetModuleHandle,NULL) 
  mov    hIcon, FUNC(LoadIcon, hInstance, 100)
  mov    hCursor, FUNC(LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW)
  mov    hBrush, FUNC(GetSysColorBrush, COLOR_APPWORKSPACE)

  Mov [wc.style], CS_HREDRAW+CS_VREDRAW+CS_GLOBALCLASS
Mov [wc.lpfnWndProc], offset WndProc 
Mov [wc.cbClsExtra], 0
Mov [wc.cbWndExtra], 0
Mov eax, [hInstance]
Mov [wc.hInstance], eax
Invoke LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
Mov [wc.hIcon], eax 
Invoke LoadCursorA,0,IDC_ARROW
Mov [wc.hCursor], eax
Mov [wc.hbrBackground], COLOR_BTNFACE+1
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszMenuName], 0
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszClassName], offset szClassName
Invoke RegisterClassA,offset wc

Push 0
Push [hInstance] ; дескриптор
Push 0
Push 0
Push 660 ; высота
Push 778 ; ширина
Push CW_USEDEFAULT ; y
Push CW_USEDEFAULT ; x
Push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ; стиль
Push offset szTitleName ; заголовок окна
Push offset szClassName ; имя класса
Push 0 ; дополнительный стиль
Call CreateWindowEx ; создаём окно

mov [newhwnd], eax



invoke ShowWindow,[newhwnd],SW_SHOWNORMAL
invoke UpdateWindow, [newhwnd]

          invoke CreateWindowEx,0,
                            chr$("BUTTON"),
                            chr$("Привет"),
                            WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON or \
                            WS_TABSTOP,
                            10,10,100,100,
                            newhwnd,NULL,
                            hInstance,NULL

invoke ShowWindow,[newhwnd],SW_SHOWNORMAL
invoke UpdateWindow, [newhwnd]
    StartLoop:
      invoke GetMessage,ADDR msg,NULL,0,0
      cmp eax, 0
      je ExitLoop
      invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
      invoke DispatchMessage,  ADDR msg
      jmp StartLoop
    ExitLoop:
 invoke ExitProcess,eax


WndProc proc uses ebx edi esi, hwnd:DWORD, wmsg:DWORD, wparam:DWORD, lparam:DWORD

Cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
Je wmdestroy
Cmp [wmsg], WM_KEYDOWN
Je wmkeydown
Invoke DefWindowProcA,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    ; вызываем стандартный обработчик сообщений
Jmp finish
wmkeydown:
cmp [wparam], VK_ESCAPE
je wmdestroy; если нажата клавиша Escape то выход
jmp finish
wmdestroy:
invoke PostQuitMessage, 0
invoke ExitProcess, 0   ; выход
finish: 
ret
WndProc endp
End start
```

UPD : Ну вот что за дела? Почему оно так не хочет русский текст выводить :*(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тексту в окне, у вас исходник сохранен в кодировке UTF-8, а нужна по факту cp1251. Пересохраните исходник в "правильной" кодировке, тогда нормально будет выводиться.

Comment: Нет, не хочет и всё, тему обновил.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, то что вы показали на скриншотах, это не перекодировка, это смена отображения на cp1251, сама кодировка файла при этом не меняется. Вам нужно вернуться к отображению в UTF-8, а потом выбрать пункт "Преобразовать в ANSI".

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, помогло :D

Comment: Вы поправьте ответ и я отмечу вопрос как решённый 

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, а что тут поправлять? Добавить информацию, как конкретно сделать перекодировку в Notepad++? Это уже лишнее. В разных редакторах это делается по-разному, а в ответе и так дана достаточная информация, чтобы решить проблему.

Comment: Ладно так и быть )